# convert a jQuery code to a pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to convert a jQuery code to a pure JavaScript and I'm stuck at this :

```
    $(window).on({
      resize: someFunction,
      scroll: someOtherFunction
    }).trigger("resize").trigger("scroll")
```

Any hints ?

Comment: jquery is created from javascript only..and it created such way that supported by most of the browser ...i dont know what is purpose of converring jquery to javascript

Comment: I'm not concerned about older browsers < IE 10

Comment: many common translations at http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the event handlers can be done as follows:

```
window.onresize = someFunction;
document.body.onscroll = someOtherFunction;
```

Triggering the events is a little more complex. You can see the jQuery source for **trigger()** on [GitHub](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L277)

Comment: probably the trigger in this context is only used for calling the functions at page load, so just do `someFunction(); someOtherFunction()` after that

Comment: Yes, that works fine unless the event object is required.

Comment: @ JohnKiller, you are right,  the trigger is only used for calling the functions at page load and someFunction(); someOtherFunction(); does the job. Thanks.